# Laravel - Cashier - Stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have created an app that implements monthly subscriptions (Laravel - cashier - stripe).  It works great in test and exactly how I want it but when I migrate to production and a user subscribes, cashier returns null when calling subscribed.  I implemented some debugging and subscriptions are returning null.  In test it returns exactly what it is supposed to.  I have updated keys to production keys.  The customer data is updated in database correctly.  I am at a loss as to why subscriptions are returning null.  Any ideas?

Tried calling subscribed and subscriptions.  Null returned.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can then start writing an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [mre] to improve it before submitting it.

Comment: you haven't shared much details (like your code) so we don't know what the root issue is. Recommend you add logs to your code and log out everything around your `subscribed()` function, to see what the values are and why something is `null` when it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it turns out there was a typo in the webhook url so the subscription table was not being populated.  This is now resolved.